# Does setting Max Time Out in Marklogic 4.2.9 need the server to be restarted?

Tags: marklogic

I am updating the **XDBC** server configurations on my clustered ML 4.2.9 server using

```
admin:appserver-set-max-time-limit($config,$id,$maxTimeLimit )
admin:save-configuration-without-restart()
```

However, after setting this configuration, MarkLogic specifies 2 ways of persisting this change.

> 1. admin:save-configuration-without-restart()
> 2. admin:save-configuration()

For 1, The ML documentation states 
"If you use this function to save any changes that require a server restart ("cold" changes such as App Server port assignment changes), then the changes will not take effect until the next time MarkLogic Server restarts (although they will be saved in the configuration)"

Can some one please tell me, whether `admin:appserver-set-max-time-limit` is a cold change or hot. Meaning, will my changes be effective ASAP if I use `admin:save-configuration-without-restart()` (which I am planning to use).
Otherwise I will have to roll these changes as planned activities so that the server downtime can be factored in.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the xquery

```
admin:appserver-set-max-time-limit($config,$id,$maxTimeLimit )
admin:save-configuration-without-restart()
```

and set the $maxTimeLimit=60 secs and I can still see other XQueries running beyond 1 min. So, I guess this change needs a cold restart of the server.

But, please do let me know if anyone know otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It is a hot change. You can see this in the admin UI: 'max time limit' does not have an asterisk (*) next to it.

But your code looks funny, and I think that is why it isn't working. Take another look at the example at http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/admin.xml&category=Admin+Library&function=admin:save-configuration-without-restart

```
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $spec := admin:forest-set-enabled($config, 
  xdmp:forest("myForest"), fn:true() )
return
  admin:save-configuration-without-restart($spec)
```

Your code is missing the argument to admin:save-configuration-without-restart(), so it will do nothing. Furthermore it's crucial to save the new version of the config. XQuery variables are normally immutable, so the sample does this using a new variable. You can also recycle the same variable name, although it's important to understand that this is reuse not mutation.

```
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $config := admin:forest-set-enabled($config,
  xdmp:forest("myForest"), fn:true() )
return
  admin:save-configuration-without-restart($config)
```

Or this is closer to what I usually do, using `xdmp:set` for mutation. I wouldn't use `xdmp:set` in most application code, but for deployment the benefits outweigh the disadvantage of introducing mutability.

```
declare variable $CFG := admin:get-configuration() ;

xdmp:set(
  $CFG, admin:forest-set-enabled($CFG, xdmp:forest("myForest"), fn:true())
,
admin:save-configuration-without-restart($CFG)
```

One way to test this is to go look at the admin UI. If it doesn't reflect your changes, with or without a restart, then something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @harry Next to the elaborate answer from Michael Blakeley, the response of `admin:save-configuration-without-restart should also tell you whether a restart is necessary. It returns a list of ids of all hosts that need a restart. If empty, no restarts are necessary..

Comment: @grtjn Thanks man. I completely missed reading the "usage" section in the API Docs. Thanks for pointing out. Great.

Answer (score 0):

@mblakele Here's the actual code that I used

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

declare variable $maxTimeLimit := 60;
declare variable $defaultTimeLimit := 60;

if ($defaultTimeLimit<=$maxTimeLimit) 
then ( 
    let $config := admin:get-configuration()
    let $groupid := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")
    let $ids:= admin:group-get-xdbcserver-ids($config, $groupid)
    return (
            for $id in $ids 
                        return 
            let $new_config := admin:appserver-set-max-time-limit($config,$id,$maxTimeLimit )
                let $final_config := admin:appserver-set-default-time-limit($new_config,$id,$defaultTimeLimit )
                return admin:save-configuration-without-restart($final_config)

))
else ()
```

This does the trick for me and I can see in the Admin UI, that the time out value has been updated. But, when I run another XQuery which usually takes more than 60 secs, it is not timed out. Any reason why?
Also, the example at [http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/admin.xml&category=Admin+Library&function=admin:save-configuration-without-restart](http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/admin.xml&category=Admin%20Library&function=admin%3asave-configuration-without-restart) does not talk about ussing the `admin:forest-set-enabled($config,xdmp:forest("myForest"), fn:true() )`

Is calling admin:forest-set-enabled really required? As I can see the config changes are stored (although they are not effective)

Comment: My bad, I changed the xdbc server config and was testing the http server timeout using cq. My xquery above does the trick for me.

Comment: Glad it's working. The call to `forest-set-enabled` was just an example, nothing to do with setting max-time-limit specifically.